# C++ vector erase at specific index doesn't get it to work

Tags: c++, vector, erase

My problem is that when I try to erase a secefic object in my vector it removes all the object before that object.

I've done this in the Bullet class, can it have something to do with it?:

```
Bullet operator=(Bullet);

Bullet Bullet::operator=(Bullet b) {
    Bullet newBullet(NULL, NULL);
    return(newBullet);
}
```

If I don't have this I get

> error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Bullet'

This is where I define each element to the bullets vector:

```
if (p_shoot) {
    bullets.insert(bullets.begin(), Bullet(p_getHitboxX(), p_getHitboxY() + (p_getHitboxH() / 2)));
    p_shoot = false;
}
```

This is the code where it happens:

```
if (!bullets.empty()) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < bullets.size();) {
        if (bullets.at(i).bullet_collisionCheck(rect)) {
            bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
        }
        else i++;
    }
}
```

I don't get it why it removes all the Bullet objects before the specific Bullet object in the index I want to erase. It's like it removes all objects between bullets.begin() and i.

Let's say that bullets contains 3 Bullet objects, the first bullet collides making bullet_collisionCheck return true, which means that the index is 0 but then it erases bullets[2] first then bullets[1] and lastly bullets[0] the one i wanted to erase first.

I've been experimenting a bit to see what's going on so I wrote this code to see exactly what happens:

```
bullets.push_back(Bullet(100, 100));
bullets.push_back(Bullet(200, 200));
bullets.push_back(Bullet(300, 300));
bullets.push_back(Bullet(400, 400));
bullets.push_back(Bullet(500, 500));
bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + 3);
```

When this code runs, it should remove the Bullet(400, 400) but it removes the last, Bullet(500, 500). I changed the value to 1 which means it should remove Bullet(200, 200) but it still removes the last, Bullet(500, 500). What is going on?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure? When erasing `bullets[0]` the following elements are moved down one position, making it perhaps look like `bullets[2]` disappeared.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes I'm very sure. When I debug and look at the elements of bullets I see that indeed the very last element was removed. Somehow...

Comment: Try this:     for (unsigned int i = 0;i < bullets.size(); i++) {
        if (bullets.at(i).bullet_collisionCheck(rect)) {
            bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i); --i;
        }
    }

Comment: @Evgeniy331 it didn't work. I still get the same result. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Rock - Ok, then we might want to see what a bullet looks like, to figure out what happens when the `vector` code moves it around.

Comment: Not addressing the issue directly, but you should consider using erase-remove idiom for such things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom  . If you re using c++11, then you can provide a lambda instead of the unary predicate function

Comment: @Arunmu how do I do that with the code I've got?

Comment: can you post the code of checkCollision?

Comment: @MohamedElHousseine the code of checkCollision is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: bullets.erase(std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(),
                [&rect](const Bullet& b) {
                   if (b.bullet_collisionCheck()) return true; return false;
                } ), bullets.end());

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem, thank you all for your help.

The problem was:

```
Bullet operator=(Bullet);

Bullet Bullet::operator=(Bullet b) {
    Bullet newBullet(NULL, NULL);
    return(newBullet);
}
```

I just had to change it to :

```
void operator=(const Bullet &b);

void Bullet::operator=(const Bullet &b) {
    bullet_hitbox.x = b.bullet_hitbox.x;
    bullet_hitbox.y = b.bullet_hitbox.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:
Just using iterating based on iterators and not on indexing.

```
if(!bullets.empty()) 
    {
        for ( auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); ++it ) 
        {
            if ( it->bullet_collisionCheck(rect) ) 
            {
                it = bullets.erase( it );
                --it;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't compile this because of there's no i.

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: That seems weird.
I had the similar code running here, which seems to work fine.
The only possibility I see which can alter the behavior is "it->bullet_collisionCheck(rect)" check,
I will recommand you to debug it thoroughly and see what is going wrong, As far as logic is concerned it seems fine.
Good luck.!

Comment: The thing is that I can replace checkCollision with if(bullets.at(i).bullet_getHitbox().x > 500) which means if the bullets x coordinate gets bigger than 500 it's true. If I do that I still get the same problem. So there's no problem in checkCollision. But thanks for your effort.

Comment: What happens if you erase the last element in the vector? `--it;` will not be valid.

Comment: As per the logic written,
When you delete the last element(it pointing to last element of vector):
it = bullets.erase( it );
after this call it will point to bullets.end(),
Since you are decremented it, it will again point to last but one position.
Hmm, but then in that case if your vector contains only 1 item and you want to delete that you are again in trouble.
My bad not written very cleverly. Will see some better alternative

Answer (score 0):

Adding new objects using "bullets.insert(bullets.begin(),..." is adding new object to the begining, so first created bullet that makes bullet_collisionCheck returning true will be last one (bullets[2]).
I think the condition `if (bullets.at(i).bullet_collisionCheck(rect))` causes the problems, because `bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);` should work fine.